# How to integrate Drift bot JS code with a static React NextJs application(landing page)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, integration, chatbot

I am new to ReactJS. I developed a landing page/static website using ReactJS & NextJs. Now I am trying to integrate a chatbot 'Drift'. In the installation process they say that to install I have to insert JavaScript code in the `<head>` of HTML files. I found the automatically created html files of my react app and inserted this code but nothing happened.

```
<script>
"use strict";

!function() {
  var t = window.driftt = window.drift = window.driftt || [];
  if (!t.init) {
    if (t.invoked) return void (window.console && console.error && console.error("Drift snippet included twice."));
    t.invoked = !0, t.methods = [ "identify", "config", "track", "reset", "debug", "show", "ping", "page", "hide", "off", "on" ], 
    t.factory = function(e) {
      return function() {
        var n = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        return n.unshift(e), t.push(n), t;
      };
    }, t.methods.forEach(function(e) {
      t[e] = t.factory(e);
    }), t.load = function(t) {
      var e = 3e5, n = Math.ceil(new Date() / e) * e, o = document.createElement("script");
      o.type = "text/javascript", o.async = !0, o.crossorigin = "anonymous", o.src = "https://js.driftt.com/include/" + n + "/" + t + ".js";
      var i = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      i.parentNode.insertBefore(o, i);
    };
  }
}();
drift.SNIPPET_VERSION = '0.3.1';
drift.load('xxxxxxxx');
</script>
<!-- End of Async Drift Code -->
```

When I inspected the landing page in localhost, I couldn't find this script in the `<header>`

Comment: If you are using ReactJs then you should install and run using npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-driftjs)

Comment: Have you tried to put header code inside public/index.html file?

Comment: I tried doing that, but there's not much to go on form there. 
`import Drift from 'react-driftjs
<Drift appId="xxxxx" />  //get the appId from drift.com`
Am I supposed to import Drift in Index.js? Also where would I get the **AppId**? I have looked around in the dashboard, contacted their support but still clueless.

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan yes. I did try putting it in the header. When I save and reload the site on local host nothing happens. I view the html code of my site in the browser using inspect element, the script is not there in the <head>

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by using `npm i react-drifts` and then importing **Drift** into my react app. Then I used `<Drift appId='xxxx'/>`. The appId is embedded in the the javascript script [`drift.load('xxxxxxxx')`] that drifts gives you to add in the `<head/>`

Comment: npm i react-driftjs